# How to pass operator in label in titanium alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have label

```
<Label id="textArea" text="0" />
```

I want to add numbers and operators in label, numbers are showing in label but operators are not showing in label.
Same value I tried in console as

```
Ti.API.info('label = ' + $.textArea.text);
```

It is showing in console but not in label in app, why so?

Please help I am new in titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this, as I understand your question, is to create the text elsewhere.

```js
var text = 'The text is 8 + 5 = 13';
$.textArea.setText(text);
```

If you are having trouble with the operators showing, maybe you are executing the sum operation (as per my text example) in javascript and not adding it as a string?

Failing example:

```
$.textArea.setText('The text is ' + 8 + 5 + ' = 13');
```

Hope this helps